# Appending the extra parameters to the anchor tag of wordpress menu?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i am working with wordpress menu. the menu is displayed to the page by the following code

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'my-menu' ,'menu_class'=> 'nav navbar-nav') ); ?>
```

it  is show anchor tag like this

```
http://website_url/examplepage/
```

How to append extra parameters to this anchor tag like this

```
http://website_url/examplepage?example=firstexample
```

Comment: have you tried in wp-admin menu section custom menu link

Comment: i am calling that menu in three different templates and menu changes according to templates condition

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom walker to achieve this. [Here](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output) is a detailed explanation about it.

OR

Also, here is a possible workaround:

Edit `nav-menu-template.php` file which is under `wp-includes` folder. Edit line no. 120 (Wordpress 3.8.1) which would look like this

```
$atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
```

Here you can add your custom parameters that you want to add. For example:

```
$atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url . 'example=firstexample' : '';
```

Note: these changes would be overridden once you update your Wordpress installation.